# how to access rosaria/sonar pointcloud data

Tags: ros, sonar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i used rostopic echo /RosAria/sonar
it showed points:
which showed x,y,z,data
I want to access these x,y,z data with a cpp file.
i'm trying  msg->points.data()

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236653/how-to-access-rosaria/sonar-pointcloud-data/) by [Himanshu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27127/himanshu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-06-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Himanshu,
You can access the x,y data of all the channels of sonar in the following manner.

` void sonarCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud::ConstPtr& msg)
{

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    datax=msg->points[i].x;
    datay=msg->points[i].y;
    ROS_INFO("[%f]",datax);
    ROS_INFO("[%f]",datay);
}
ROS_INFO("....");
```

}`
you can refer to the sensor_msgs/PointCloud for details.

---

Originally posted by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) with karma: 28 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0